# MySql column names of a query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Am I able to write a stored procedure with a parameter, which is the mysql query and the stored procedure returns the column names of the query?

For example I call the procedure:

call selector('select * from users')

And the procedure returns the column names. 
It would be easy with information.schema but if I have a more complicated query and alias in it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selector`(
    IN `sql_query` VARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGiN
drop table if exists tmp111;
SET @sql = concat('create table tmp111 as ', sql_query);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Execute stmt;
describe tmp111;
END
```

Then call it like:

```
call selector('select name as n, email as e from users')
```

Comment: add a `limit 0` to the sql in `SET @sql ...`. this will prevent a very large table from being created